# Unit test for Json

Tags: c#, unit-testing

What will be the unit test for below code:

```
public JsonResult Test()
    {
        return Json(new { Result = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I have written:

```
public void Test_Returns_SuccessData()
    {

        var result = testFactory.WebController.Test() as JsonResult;
        Xunit.Assert.NotNull(result);
        Xunit.Assert.NotNull(result.Data);
    }
```

But it is showing null exception.

Comment: Please always try adding the programming language as a "tag".

Comment: Which line is throwing the null exception?

Comment: var result = testFactory.WebController.Test() as JsonResult; This line is showing null exception.